# azure media services streaming url generate dynamically on server side (using Razor MVC .Net )

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have a manifest url that i need to display at the src below .How can i display it from server side Code using ASP.Net MVC    .My question is how are azure streaming urls to be used within an existing web application?

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>


       <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
                <source src= "manifestUrl"type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />

            </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options at least:

1. Use server variable in javascritpt such as below:

source src= <%url%> type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />

where url is a C# variable in ASP.NET controller in which you assign the full URL to url variable.

2. Usually you may want to allow end users to enter/update the URL through a textbox. To do this you can choose to databind a textbox to a Model in MVC. The model should have a URL property which is then bound to the textbox. This is common technique ASP.NET MVC databinding technique and you can easily find lots of samples.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I am using MVC application.Is it possible to set the manifest url retrieved as an ajax response ?(data from Json result method in the controller returns the url which i want to display)

Comment: Yes, just need to make sure the Azure Media Player is initialized AFTER the stream URL is obtained and assigned to the source through the AJAX call. For example, suppose you have a button which launches a player to play video. This button could be dimmed/disabled until AJAX call is completed and the obtained URL is assigned to the source of the player.